# Javascript regex url validator is very slow?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am currently using this code to validate URL's but since i am validating highlighted text from a page it's really really slow for a javascript function.

Here is the code i am using:

```
    var urlregex = new RegExp(
        "^(http|https|ftp)\://([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+(\:[a-zA-Z0-9\.&amp;%\$\-]+)*@)*((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[0-9])|([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.(com|edu|gov|int|mil|net|org|biz|arpa|info|name|pro|aero|coop|museum|[a-zA-Z]{2}))(\:[0-9]+)*(/($|[a-zA-Z0-9\.\,\?\'\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~_\-]+))*$");
return urlregex.test($.trim(url));
```

I hope that there is other methods that i can use to check for valid links using javascript.

Thanks.

Comment: How did you measure the slowness? Do you have a http://jsperf.com case?

Comment: Just a remark: using a string in a character class wont work: each char in &amp; will be handled alone in `[a-zA-Z0-9\.&amp;%\$\-]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is considerably slower to use `expr = new RegExp("pattern")` vs. `expr = /pattern/g`. You should also make sure that you compile the expression outside of your function definition so it can be reused without being compiled every time the function is called (even more important if it is inside a loop). Try the following:

```
var expression = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/i;
function testUrl(url){
    return expression.test($.trim(url));
}
```

You can see more about javascript regular expression performance here: http://corporate.tuenti.com/en/dev/blog/tips-and-tricks-with-regular-expressions-in-js

Comment: Extremely huge difference, thank you very much. Your info was very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Try with below Regex:

```
var url1 = /(^|&lt;|\s)(www\..+?\..+?)(\s|&gt;|$)/g;
var url2 = /(^|&lt;|\s)(((https?|ftp):\/\/|mailto:).+?)(\s|&gt;|$)/g;
```